# No se guardan los datos en el postgresql del servidor Heroku

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, express, heroku, pgadmin

Les muestro imagenes y codigo para hacerme entender lo mas facil posible, ya que lo que estoy haciendo es algo sencillo. Mi idea es hacer consultas a **postgresql de Heroku** con mi **API** de **node/express** de forma local. Entonces: simplemente cree una app en **Heroku**, fui a la **opcion de add-ons** y elegi **Heroku Postgres**. Despues **copié las credenciales** para conectarme desde **pgAdminIII**. y tambien copie esas credenciales en mi **archivo de configuracion de base de datos** en **node/express**.
Con **pgAdmin** cree una **tabla user** con dos campos: **email y password**. Me fijé en el **dashboard de Heroku** y efectivamente me muestra que se creó la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahi todo bien, pero:

1. hago la prueba **POST** para crear un usuario con un cliente Rest como **INSOMNIA**, y como respuesta obtengo que el usuario fue creado, pero cuando me fijo desde el **pgAdmin** veo que no guardo nada y ademas muestra un campo "name" que no existe en mi tabla user.

**Aca cuando hago el POST con Insomnia**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Miren cuando me fijo desde pgAdminIII**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien probé haciendo un **INSERT directamente desde pgAdmin**, no me tira errores pero tampoco guarda los datos. ¿Que hay que hacer para que funcione como corresponde?

**Aca les muestro lo que tengo en node/express**

Asi tengo mi archivo **database.ts** **donde puse las credenciales** (les muestro con datos ficticios).

```js
import {Pool} from 'pg';

export const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'fbzxxxxxxxx',
    host: 'ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
    password: '08xxxxxed4e75f58060226ed70ebc431c77xxxx783ae2c1fb859840edbb64ac',
    database: 'd19xxxxxl1xxxx',
    ssl: { "rejectUnauthorized": false },
    port: 5432
})
```

**RUTA**

```js
import {Router} from 'express'
const router = Router();
import {createUser} from '../controllers.ts/index.controller';

router.post('/users', createUser)

export default router;
```

**CONTROLADOR**

```js
import {Request, Response} from 'express';
import {QueryResult} from 'pg';
import {pool} from '../database';
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt'); 

export const createUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
      res.status(400).send("FALTA CONTENIDO EN EL CUERPO");
      return;
    }
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log("Datos recibidos: ", email, password);
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10); // encripta el password
    // insert en PostgreSQL
    await pool
      .query(
        "INSERT INTO public.user (email, password) VALUES ($1, $2)",
        [email, hash]
      )
      .then((data) => {
        res.status(200).send({ message: "The user was inserted successfuly" });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res
          .status(400).send({
            message:
              "Error to insert user " + error,
          });
      });
  };
```

Comment: esto suele suceder ya que el modo autocommit esta desactivado por defecto, prueba agregando una instruccion COMMIT inmediatamente despues de ejecutar tu insercion

Comment: Gracias por responder, te refereis a que la query sea asi: INSERT INTO public.user (email, password) VALUES ($1, $2) COMMIT;